# How to input a string from user into environment variable from batch file

Tags: input, batch-file, cmd

I want to prompt the user for some input detail, and then use it later as a command line argument.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use `set` with the `/p` argument:

> `SET /P variable=[promptString]`
>
> The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input
>   entered by the user.  Displays the specified promptString before reading
>   the line of input.  The promptString can be empty.

So, simply use something like

```
set /p Input=Enter some text:
```

Later you can use that variable as argument to a command:

```
myCommand %Input%
```

Be careful though, that if your input might contain spaces it's probably a good idea to quote it:

```
myCommand "%Input%"
```

Comment: Is something like that for input password ?

Comment: There are numerous answers to this, usually via a VBScript to get the password without echoing to the console.

Comment: I used this to ask for input file path to give to an EXE, but if that PATH also contains an environment variable ("%MY_SRC_DIR%\blabla\file.ext") it doesn't work, I have to give it the absolute or relative file path without the environment variable. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @dominicbri7: You'd need to expand the environment variable, that is, make it visible twice to the `cmd` parser. `call set Input=%Input%` would be a way. This would be parsed twice (due to the `call`), expanding `%Input%` the first time and whatever environment variables you have in there the second time. But this doesn't really have anything to do with this question or answer.

Answer (score 2):

A rather roundabout way, just for completeness:

```
 for /f "delims=" %i in ('type CON') do set inp=%i
```

Of course that requires ^Z as a terminator, and so the Johannes answer is better in all practical ways.

Comment: That one is ... interesting. Now you only need to educate the user that only her *last* line entered will be used :-)