# Batch dialogue to choose directory to run batch?

Tags: batch-file, directory, directory-structure

Is there any way to display a dialogue that allows the user to select which directory to run the batch within?  (from a list of directories, and maybe an option to manually input a directory path?)

I'd imagine it'd look like:

```
echo Choose a directory to run script:
SET /P ANS=Directory 1, 2, 3, 4, <etc>
if /i {%ANS%}=={1} (goto :1)
if /i {%ANS%}=={2} (goto :2)
:: <etc>

:1
<code to designate directory to run in>
<code for operations>
:2
<etc>
```

but I'm not sure how to designate the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CHOICE command. The user can enter a number and then the ERRORLEVEL variable is set accordingly. See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php) for more details.

EDIT: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515965/how-to-input-a-string-from-user-into-environment-variable-from-batch-file) question for string prompts.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should work a charm:

```
:start
set /p dir=Choose a directory: 
cls
if exist %dir% (cd %dir%) else echo Directory not found. & goto start
```

Or, if you wanted a list of directories to choose from:

```
echo Option 1
echo Option 2
echo Etc...
choice /c 123
::Replace "{directory}" with a folder path.
if errorlevel 3 cd {directory}
if errorlevel 2 cd {directory}
if errorlevel 1 cd {directory}
```

There's endless ways to choose from.