# Create a new file using BATCH

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to create a BATCH file that lets user input a file name and generates a file with that name and the content from another file (`stam.txt`).

```
@echo enter name file
@set /p newfile=%=%
@set /a newfile=%newfile%.txt
cd C:\add
type stam.txt > newfile
```

But I always get a file called new file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input a string from user into environment variable from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515965/how-to-input-a-string-from-user-into-environment-variable-from-batch-file)

Comment: `1.` `@Set /P "newfile=Enter a file name: "`, `2.` `@Copy /Y "C:\add\stam.txt" "%newfile%">NUL 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
@echo enter name file
@set /p newfile=%=%
cd C:\add
type stam.txt > %newfile%.txt
```